# My Maui Android 12 application cannot access my application/files folder?

Tags: android-12

I created a .net m.a.u.i for android 10 emulator and create files and images in **root_Dir/files**

```
root_Dir = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null)?.AbsolutePath;

=> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/jmd.TakeCopyPhotos/files
```

(The folder **imagesDirectory** is a subdir of root_Dir)
This application uses CapturePhotoAsync() and copy the photos in imagesDirectory folder without problems.
And when I use (I view *filesList* contents in Debug mode):

IEnumerable *filesList* =   Directory.EnumerateFiles(**imagesDirectory**);

*filesList* contains the taken photos.
After that I can PickPhotoAsync() photos that are in root_Dir.
All that in Android 10 emulator and real phone.

My problem is :
When I do the same in **Android 12** I cannot see the folder root_Dir contents !!!
All I see when using PickPhotoAsync() and trying to browse to root_Dir is :
[image]
Can anyone explain this ?

I cannot find the problem with Android 12.

Note that using the Files application on my phone, I can browse and see the contents of root_Dir under Android 12.
Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: No answers.  Nobody can help me please ?

Comment: No answers ! What can I do?

Comment: No one answer !!! Help me please.

Comment: Oh, no response !!!